# How to validate Checkbox,radio button,dropdownlist using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

Product.aspx

```
    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlProduct" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Mac">Mac</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="iPad">iPad</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="iPhone">iPhone</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="iPod">iPod</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Accessories">Accessories</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="clearForm(oForm)"/>
```

see this javascript code :

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#form1").validate({



           rules: {
               ddlCcity: { required: true },
                ddlProduct: { required: true }
           }

       });

       $.validator.addMethod(
    "select_class",
    function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (value.indexOf("--Select One--") ==-1);
    },
    "Please select a class.");

   });


    function clearForm(oForm) {
    var elements = oForm.elements;
       oForm.reset();
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       field_type = elements.type.toLowerCase();
       switch (field_type) {
          case "text":
           case "password":
            case "textarea":
             case "dropdownlist":
             elements.value = "";
                break;
                case "radio":
                case "checkbox":

                if (elements.checked) {

                    elements.checked = false;

                }

                break;
            case "select-one":
            case "select-multi":

                elements.selectedIndex = 0;

                break;



            default:

                break;

        }

    }
}
    </script>
```

In Product.aspx i use the validation.js(javascript code),but the validation is not working
how to validate dropdownlist,checkbox,radio button using javascript code

Comment: *Very low quality:* What "isn't working"? What have you tried?

Comment: It looks like you've posted only a partial javascript code, and even the functions are incomplete. Fix them first and also tell us which javascript function you called to validate, and what was the result instead of merely saying it is not working.

Comment: Please check this .Its very helping to you [javascript-validation-textbox-combobox-radiobutton-checkbox](http://jesin.tk/javascript-validation-textbox-combobox-radiobutton-checkbox/)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
function validate(){
var i=0;
if($('#CheckBox1').is(":checked")==false){
i++;
}
if($('#RadioButton1').is(":checked")==false){
i++;
}
if($('#ddlProduct').val()==""){
i++;
}
if(i>0){
return false;
}else{
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: $("#form1").submit(function () {
            return $(this).validation();
            alert("submitted");
        });